# org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException - How to get a null value out of database?

Tags: java, hibernate, null

Here is the exception:

*org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of com.FOO.hibernate.Tccl.MIN.*

I found that this exception happen when i try to get the null value from MIN column. There're some solutions for this issue:

- Set "NULL" (a string) for MIN column
- Set default value, like 0 or 0.0.

But MIN column has the INT type and 0 or 0.0 is such a value in my case.

Here is my code:

```
        String HQL_QUERY = "from Tccl tccl";
        Query query = session.createQuery(HQL_QUERY);
        List<Tccl> list = query.list();
        for(Tccl tccl : list){
               //fetch data here
        }
```

The exception happen at:

```
 List<Tccl> list = query.list();
```

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 5):

You should use the Object type `Integer` for your field "MIN" of the Tccl class instead of the primitive type `int`.
This will allow null values.